# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused ddev-router healthcheck endpoint not responding

Tags: docker, ddev

DDEV-Local version  v1.13.1
commit              v1.13.1
db                  drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.2:v1.13.0
dba                 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5
ddev-ssh-agent      drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.13.0
docker              19.03.8
docker-compose      1.25.0-rc4
os                  linux
router              drud/ddev-router:v1.13.0
web                 drud/ddev-webserver:v1.13.1

Composer version 1.9.3 2020-02-04 12:58:49

```
Starting d8views... 
Building ddev-ssh-agent 
Creating ddev-ssh-agent ... done

ssh-agent container is running: If you want to add authentication to the ssh-agent container, run 'ddev auth ssh' to enable your keys. 
Pushing mkcert rootca certs to ddev-global-cache 
Pushed mkcert rootca certs to ddev-global-cache 
Running   Command=ip address show dev docker0
ddev needs to add an entry to your hostfile.
It will require administrative privileges via the sudo command, so you may be required
to enter your password for sudo. ddev is about to issue the command: 
    sudo /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ddev/1.13.1/bin/ddev hostname d8views.ddev.site 127.0.0.1 
Please enter your password if prompted. 
Running   Command=sudo /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ddev/1.13.1/bin/ddev hostname d8views.ddev.site 127.0.0.1
[sudo] password for james: 
Building db 
Building web 
Creating ddev-d8views-db ... done
Creating ddev-d8views-dba ... done
Creating ddev-d8views-web ... done

Creating ddev-router ... done

Failed to start d8views: ddev-router failed to become ready: logOutput=nginx config: OK  nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
ddev-router healthcheck endpoint not responding 
, err=container /ddev-router unhealthy: nginx config: OK  nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
ddev-router healthcheck endpoint not responding
```

So I ran ddev describe to see what's what:

```
ddev describe
NAME     TYPE     LOCATION            URL                        STATUS        
d8views  drupal8  ~/Projects/d8views  https://d8views.ddev.site  running

Project Information
-------------------
PHP version:    7.3
MariaDB version    
MySQL version      

URLs
----
http://d8views.ddev.site 
http://127.0.0.1:32786   
https://d8views.ddev.site
https://127.0.0.1:32785  

MySQL/MariaDB Credentials
-------------------------
Username: "db", Password: "db", Default database: "db"

or use root credentials when needed: Username: "root", Password: "root"

Database hostname and port INSIDE container: db:3306
To connect to db server inside container or in project settings files: 
mysql --host=db --user=db --password=db --database=db
Database hostname and port from HOST: 127.0.0.1:32784
To connect to mysql from your host machine, 
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=32784 --user=db --password=db --database=db

Other Services
--------------
MailHog:    http://d8views.ddev.site:8025
phpMyAdmin: http://d8views.ddev.site:8036

DDEV ROUTER STATUS: healthy 
ssh-auth status: healthy
```

I have ddev on another laptop that runs fine but all of the versions are older, is something missing here on this setup? I noticed that I have to provide a password during the initial ddev start process.

Comment: I've seen this a few times on older computers. Does this Linux device have an SSD or hard drive? There's actually a PR that needs to be tested that might fix this, if you could try it out it would be great. If it's like the other cases, if you `ddev list` a few seconds after the failure, it shows everything being OK. The PR you could test is https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/2123 and I'll put instructions on how to get the artifacts there.

Comment: Anyway, please follow up in the PR, https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/2123 or the related issue, https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2120

Comment: system info -
Kernel: 5.3.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0 
Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 2.24.32)
Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Device: laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ENVY 14 Sleekbook v: 087210000D305B00100320100
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 264.1GB (38.7% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: KINGSTON_SA400S3 size: 240.1GB temp: 30C
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: LITEONIT_LMS size: 24.0GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 219G used: 96G (46%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2

I will go to the link and run a test, thanks rfay

Comment: Waiting for you over there @fndtn357 - Right now I don't have anybody who has this problem, so if it makes things work for you I'll pull it for the next release.

Comment: I don't know how to test the fix you created. I installee ddev via a linuxbrew (brew) call on my machine. Do you want me to git pull the original and go to the branch you created? How wouold I call that ddev and not the installed one on my machine?
I have been busy with other clients and didn't get back to this quick enough.

Comment: You'll need to use the instructions in https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/2123#issuecomment-609531930 - you're on Linux right? I recommend downloading the linux tarball and placing the linux binary in /usr/local/bin/ddev. Then reload your path by opening a new windows. `which ddev` should show /usr/local/bin/ddev. When your done you can `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ddev` and open a new window and you'll again be using the linuxbrew binary.

Comment: I tried to do a few other things on my laptop and realized that there was something terribly wrong with my OS (that's a first in many years). I reinstalled my OS and ddev works as advertised. Thanks for taking the time to respond thoughtfully.  Thanks rfay

Comment: Thanks for the followup @fndtn357 - glad it's working for you.